# Finding a title who matches a json value

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am looking to search through 902 `td` elements in a table and find `.row` class who's title attribute equals the json objects value.

The table looks something like this

```
<div id="site_relationship_id_tbdd">
    <table class="tbd-table">
       <tbody>
           <tr class="header">
             ...
           </tr>
           <tr class="row">
               <td title = "1"></td> // This value increments for each parent tr element.
               <td title="SomeTitle"></td>
               <td title="someJazz"></td>
           </tr>
           ... 901 more of these ....
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I have coming back as the json value is:

```
[{"site_id":"148"}]
```

and what I have for jquery so far is: `$('#site_relationship_id_tbdd .tbdd-drop .row').find('td')`
Which has been useful to find me all the `td` elements inside a `tr`.

What I want to do is find the one `td` element who's `title="148"` and then add `.selected` to the parent `tr`, so it will look like: `<tr class="row selected>`

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine it with attribute as well.

```
$('#site_relationship_id_tbdd .tbdd-drop .row').find('td[title="148"]')
                                         .closest('tr')
                                         .addClass('selected');
```

If you have multiple siteids like this in the array, then you can try:

```
var ids = [{"site_id":"1"}, {"site_id":"2"}, {"site_id":"148"}];
//create the selector
var selector = ids.map(function(o){
     return "td[title=" + o['site_id'] + "]";
}).join(',');

var $elem = $('#site_relationship_id_tbdd .tbd-table .row')
                       .find(selector)
                       .closest('tr')
                       .addClass('selected');
```

Comment: I should have mentioned - Which I just found out - that it only shows 5 at a time So in the source you only see 5 TD's before you can paginate through another five and so on .. the source does not have the other hidden it just updates 5 existing TR's

Comment: @LogicLooking yes you cannot do anything to the ones that are not in DOM. But did this answer give you some insights on to avoid any loops through all those tds?